# So i've never completely understood the benefit of using Private

Tags: c#, java, c++

So even though my uni course is a programming one, they never actually explained it and even i've googled it many a time, i never completely understood it. As far as security is concerned, is it better?

Im trying to write a multi-class system at the moment and am changing all the access modifiers to public, because otherwise, access will not be granted.

Can someone explain it in detail, and try and make it easy to understand?

Thanks guys

Comment: Has nothing to do with security really. Private is used to make your implementation of things class internal.

Comment: That member starts getting weird values assigned to it. Now your whole codebase has access to that member. Good luck hunting down which line among the million is responsible.

Comment: In addition to @chris comment, it also makes it easier to decide on changes. Suppose adding a feature or fixing a bug would be easier if you were to make a change in the type or meaning of a field. If it is private, all the code that might be affected is in one file, and easy to find. If not, you have a lot more work to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of `private` is called Encapsulation.

It can and should be used to organize your code. It has nothing to do with security.

The basic rule is that all data (fields) should be private and that access is only possible through public members (properties, methods).

That way an object can be made responsible for its own correct 'object state'.

Encapsulation is the simple but very powerful concept that a class should have an outside (public interface) and an inside (private implementation). Only members that are required and safe to be used by consuming code should be public.

`private` does not mean "you may not know" but it means "you don't have to know" .

Comment: So make methods public, and vars private?

Comment: All fields private, most/some methods public. A method that leaves an object in an invalid state should remain private.

Comment: Alright, so assuming i had a Form and a Class, Form foo has a label "text" which gets passed to Class bar, bar will run String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo.text.Text) and then return the value to Foo. How would i go about doing this as far as public/private modifiers go ?

Comment: See also [Information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). I think a lot of methods could be `private` too, or `protected` or `internal`. It all depends on who has to bother about them. So-called implementation details should clearly not be `public`.

Comment: The Form should not expose any controls, so create a MyForm.LabelText property. But it's still not right, the bussines layer should not know about the UI.

Comment: Could you write me a mock up on pastebin ?

Comment: No, we keep answer stuff on SO. And the Form-Class question is way beyond the original, look for tutorials on architecture and design-patterns.

Answer (score 1):

First, bugfixing becomes easier because you dont see many variables floating around with your private variables.

Maybe when you join a big project, you dont want any other programmer to access specials of your class files, everyone doing a part of work and not knowing all-project. If anyone know all-variables then he/she can sell project himself/herself secretly(finishing before team).

In the end, your private variables are not global and this alone can be an optimization(maybe not for java).

Answer (score 1):

Another point not mentioned in previous answers is effect on code maintainability - is all your variables are public an arbitrary number of classes can reference them. If you want to change the way one class works, you also need to modify all those classes. As a result you may need to change other classes' internals and you've got a beautiful butterfly effect. On the other hand if you keep internals private and only have abstract interfaces public you can modify class implementation while maintaining old interface with no changes outside the class needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speaking only about C++ here.

`private` is occasionally quite useful.  Suppose you have a reasonably big codebase.  Suppose you're trying to find all users of a field in a class, perhaps because you want to get rid of it.  You can make that field `private`.  Then you get nice, friendly compilation errors telling you exactly where all of the users are.

`private` isn't really all that great at information hiding, though, since it doesn't really hide any information.  In the case of overloaded member functions, this can be a real issue.  If a base class has a public member called `base::foo(double)` and you create a private `derived::foo(int)`, this is not an error.  However, overload resolution will find only `derived::foo`, even though it's private.

I'd also point out that the proper way to do information hiding is the [pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom)

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit to using private properties and accessing them through getters and setters is that you can use those functions to manipulate the values before they actually get set.

Here's an example. In Doctrine--which is written in PHP and used for interacting with databases--you create an object that contains values to be sent to the database. The data getting added often comes from a form. In a database, certain values can be null. Obviously, if the value from the form is empty, the value should be set as null. But that's not how it works--it simply gets set as an empty string, and you don't get the null value that you want being sent to the database.

To make this work properly, you can set up your setter function something like this:

```
public function setName($name)
{
    if ($name === '') {
        $this->name = null;
    } else {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, the function checks for an empty string, then sets the class's $name property as null if that's the case. This null value will then be sent to the database, not the empty string.

This is especially beneficial if you're using the method in a number of places. Without it, you'd have to check for empty values **each time** you set them. By having the check in the class's setter, it makes it much easier, since you don't have to think about it.